# Chef - Test variables that passed to a recipe used when starting a service

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a small recipe that is responsibe for stopping and starting a service.

This recipe is called by another in a machine execute block, that block sets a node on the server to be a specific port which is then used to target that service directly.

I'm trying to test this in isolation and am so fan unable to mock the node or set that variable.

Any help on how to achieve would be fantastic, thank you.

```
port = node['restart-port'] #this will change to 'current port' or something

solrCore = "solr_#{port}"
# solrCore = "solr_8987"

service solrCore do
  service_name solrCore
  supports :status => true, :stop => true, :start => true
  action :nothing
end

ruby_block "stop the service" do
  block do
    Chef::Log.info('triggers restart')
    notifies :stop, run_context.resource_collection.find(:service => solrCore), :immediately
    sleep 30
    notifies :run, run_context.resource_collection.find(:ruby_block => 'start the service')
  end
end

ruby_block "start the service" do
  block do
    Chef::Log.info('triggers start')
    action :nothing
    notifies :start, run_context.resource_collection.find(:service => solrCore), :immediately
  end
end
```

My pitiful test class:

```
    let(:chef_run) do
  runner = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new
  runner.converge(described_recipe)
end

it 'converges successfully' do
  expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
end

it 'has create and defined the solr service' do
  expect(chef_run).to_not enable_service('solr_port but how, node is transient')
end
```

Comment: Notifies is something you use from the resource block, not within a ruby_block like that. This code probably won't work and if it does it's purely by accident.

Comment: @coderanger - I can't remember why we changed from resource block to ruby block now - it does work though but I'll change it back to resource tomorrow and see if it still works ok. :)